# ReorderableListView physics

Tags: flutter, dart

How to specify physics for `ReorderableListView` in flutter ?
I want to use `BouncingScrollPhysics`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of writing, it is not possible to assign a `physics` property to `ReorderableListView` in Flutter.
You can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/refreshable_reorderable_list , it solves exactly that.

```
RefreshableReorderableListView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        onReorder: (){},
        children: ...
      ),
```